# Striping LVM Across Multiple MD-RAID Arrays

Tags: linux, raid, storage, lvm, dmraid

I have a machine with three, fifteen drive mdraid RAID-6 arrays (md10, md20, md30.) These three arrays are then setup as physical volumes for LVM and combined into a single volume group.

I then have been creating logical volumes from the VG using the following command:

lvcreate -i 3 -I 4 -L 10T -n

These volumes are then being served out as block devices via FCoE.

My question is if I need to do anything with the chunk/stripe sizes to make this work as well as it should? If I have 15 drive, RAID-6 arrays, does the stripe size that LVM passes down to the RAID device need to be 13x the size of the RAID chunk size (since I have double parity) so that I can actually get the full speed of all 45 drives?

OS is RHEL 7, LVM version is 2.02.115(2)-RHEL7.

Answer (score 1):

Aligning the LV chunk sizes with the RAID per-disk stripe size *might* improve performance, as it reduces the need to touch multiple disks to get a single LV chunk.  I'd be inclined to think that making the LV chunk size the array stripe size (ie 13x per-disk stripe size) wouldn't do anything for you.  If you're doing a lot of linear reads, setting a large readahead is likely to be the best performance improvement.

Given the low probability that you'll find someone who has experience with exactly your configuration, *and* given how much impact your specific workload will have on performance, I think you'll need to do a whole bunch of benchmarking to get the answer to your question.  I, for one, would be interested to see what the results are.